# Optimizing HttpWebResponse - GetResponse

Tags: optimization, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse, getresponse

I'm using the following lines of code to read the response of an asynchronous HttpWebRequest. This seems to be the largest amount of time spent in a particular operation. Is there anything I can optimize here?

```
System.Net.HttpWebResponse oResp =(System.Net.HttpWebResponse)oReq.EndGetResponse(oResult);
oResp = (HttpWebResponse)oReq.GetResponse();
StreamReader oStreamReader = new StreamReader(oResp.GetResponseStream());
string sResponse = oStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

...goes on to make an XmlDocument, append some more XML to it, then perform an XSL transform.

Creating the Connections:

```
HttpWebRequest oReq;
oReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sUrl + sQueryString);
oReq.ContentType = sContentType;
oReq.Method = "POST";
oReq.ContentLength = aBytes.Length;
Stream oStream = oReq.GetRequestStream();
oStream.Write(aBytes, 0, aBytes.Length);
oStream.Close();
AsyncState oState = new AsyncState(oReq);
return oReq.BeginGetResponse(fCallBack, oState);
```

Comment: In order to answer that, you need to collect more information. Is the delay happening on the client or the server? you mentioned that you need to create an XML document - is the server generating this document on the fly, or is it serving a document from disk? 

Are you going through a proxy?

Are you using authentication?

Are you using Tcp keep alive connections? Related to this, is this request being done in a loop, or is this a one-off application that makes just this one request and ends?

Show your code snippet of how you create your request.

And we can take it further from there..

Comment: Also, why are you calling EndGetResponse() and then GetResponse() again? That is not correct usage of the API.

Comment: Some more information:
The server is generating the xml on the fly. 
I do not use a proxy.
The calls are authenticated.
The connections are not keep alive.
The connections are one-off, no more than one connection is ever made per load.

I've added above how the request is created.

Comment: And the answer to the first question, it looks like nearly all of the time is being spent in the 

string sResponse = oStreamReader.ReadToEnd();

line, thus on the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one major improvement to the scheme I was using. Rather than using the StreamReader and ReadToEnd to get the Stream into a string, only then to convert it into an XmlDocument. I skipped the middle man and converted the Stream directly into a XmlDocument.

This left me with another problem though, I had to change the parent of the XmlDocument to fit my Xslt (there are a great many and they all expect the structure I had). See [How can I add new root element to a C# XmlDocument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269150/how-can-i-add-new-root-element-to-a-c-xmldocument) for that fix.

This has given me a roughly 2/3 decrease in the time taken to process the results of the webservice call, and a great decrease in the amount of memory used. In the previous version, the response xml was in memory two different times (maybe three if the stream counts)!

In addition, removing the extra GetResponse seemed to help.

```
using (HttpWebResponse oResp = (HttpWebResponse)oReq.EndGetResponse(oResult))
{
oXml.Load(oResp.GetResponseStream());
XmlNode oApiResult = oXml.RemoveChild(oXml.DocumentElement);
oXml.LoadXml(sOtherXml);
oXml.DocumentElement.AppendChild(oApiResult);
}
```