# How can I add new root element to a C# XmlDocument?

Tags: c#, optimization, xmldocument

I have, outside of my control, an XmlDocument which has a structure like the following:

```
<parent1>
...minor amount of data...
</parent1>
```

I have another XmlDocument, also outside of my control, which has the following structure:

```
<parent2>
..very large amount of data...
</parent2>
```

I need an XmlDocument in the format:

```
<parent1>
...minor amount of data...
<parent2>
..very large amount of data...
</parent2>
</parent1>
```

I don't want to make a copy of parent2. How can I get the structure I need, without copying parent2? I believe this means

```
oParent1.DocumentElement.AppendChild(oParent1.ImportNode(oParent2.DocumentElement, true));
```

is out of the question.

Any good solutions out there?

Comment: I see you are trying to combine XML documents.  You should totally drop that and use jQuery instead.

Comment: Not very helpful, this is server-side code written in C#.

Comment: I was joking.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19492#19492  I was basically saying that you stumped me.

Comment: The parent2 content has arrived at this point in code already loaded into an XmlDocument and you can't change that?

Comment: Is there some kind of relaitonship between <parent1> and <parent2>?  Maybe some kind of ID attribute that tells which ones to link together?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones parent 2, at this point is a Stream.

Comment: Why don't you want to make a copy of parent2?

Comment: @Ian Jacobs There is a 1 to 1 relationship between parent 1 and parent 2.

Comment: @aepheus  I just mean is there something that says which parent2's go with which parent 1s?

Comment: @user210118 I don't want to make a copy because it effectively doubles my memory usage. And, I currently have a memory problem.

Comment: @Ian Jacobs Yes, parent 2 is always a first level child of parent 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the DocumentElement from the parent2 XmlDocument, then append the imported parent1 node to the XmlDocument (directly -- NOT to the DocumentElement) and re-append the removed parent2 node to the imported parent1 node:

```
var p1node = oParent2.ImportNode(oParent1.DocumentElement, true);
var p2node = oParent2.RemoveChild(oParent2.DocumentElement);

oParent2.AppendChild(p1node);
p1node.AppendChild(p2node);
```